# Python scoreboard made by a beginner

Tags: python

```
   question: str = input("A. To check scoreboard press 1\n"
                         "B. To add a new score press 2\n"
                         "C. To overwrite an old score 3\n")


   class MyScoreboard:
       pass


   if question == "1":
       MyScoreboard()
   elif question == "2":
       y = int(input("enter your score >>"))
       score = y
       word = input("enter your name >>")
       file = open("manager.txt", 'a')
       file.write(str(score) + " >> " + word + "\n")
       print(MyScoreboard())
       file. Close()
   elif question == "3":
       file = open("manager.txt", 'r+')
       z = str(input("enter the name"))
       r = int(input("enter new score"))
       file = open("manager.txt", 'r+')
       array1, array2, array3 = [], [], {}
       lines = file.readlines()
       for x in lines:
           fields = x.split(" >> ")
           array1.append(int(fields[0]))
           array2.append(fields[1])
           name = fields[1].replace("\n", "")
           array3[int(fields[0])] = name
       if z == name:
           array1 = fields[0].replace((int(fields[0])), "r")
       else:
           array1.sort(reverse=True)
           for x in array1:
               value = array3.get(x)
               print("\n", x, ">>", value)
       file. Close()




   def MyScoreboard():
       file = open("manager.txt", 'r+')
       array1, array2, array3 = [], [], {}
       lines = file.readlines()
       for x in lines:
           fields = x.split(" >> ")
           array1.append(int(fields[0]))
           array2.append(fields[1])
           name = fields[1].replace("\n", "")
           array3[int(fields[0])] = name
       array1.sort(reverse=True)
       for x in array1:
           value = array3.get(x)
           print("\n", x, ">>", value)
       file.close()


   MyScoreboard()
```

Python scoreboard made by a beginner
so i am a beginner who was trying to make a scoreboard in python a simple one, but i cant seem to be able to replace the score of an old player with a new one? i learnt most of this of youtube so i am confused, and i can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some improvements and you can have some homework from me at the end of the answer. Here, you can find how to properly call your class to keep it being executed until you break out of the `while True:` with an input of "q":

```
# Execution starts from here
scoreboard = MyScoreboard() # get instance of your class
while True: # keep on doing it 
    print("_________________________________________________________________")
    question = input("A. To check scoreboard press 1\n"
                      "B. To add a new score press 2\n"
                      "C. To overwrite an old score press 3\n"
                      "To quit press q\n\n") # get the input from the user
    if question == "1": # if 1, then
        scoreboard.display_scores() # display summary of scores, you should already have the manager.txt
    elif question == "2": # if 2, then add new player
        y = int(input("Enter your score >> ")) # the score
        word = input("Enter your name >> ") # the player
        scoreboard.add_score(y, word) # add the player
        scoreboard.display_scores() # display the score optional.
    elif question == "3": # if 3, then update score of player
        scoreboard.overwrite_score() # overwrite the score
        scoreboard.display_scores() # again, optional displaying of the score
    elif question.lower() == "q": # if q is detected then exit
        break # break out of the loop
    else: # otherwise print out invalid and continue
        print("Invalid input. Please try again.")
print("_________________________________________________________________") # for niceness
print("Scoreboard summary:") # summary...
scoreboard.display_scores()
```

As for the class:

```
class MyScoreboard:
    def display_scores(self):
        file = open("manager.txt", 'r+')  # open file for reading and writing
        array1, array2, array3 = [], [], {}  # initialize empty lists and dictionary
        lines = file.readlines()  # read all lines from the file
        for x in lines:
            fields = x.split(" >> ")
            array1.append(int(fields[0]))  # convert score to int and append to array1
            array2.append(fields[1].replace("\n", ""))  # remove newline and append name to array2
            array3[int(fields[0])] = array2[-1]  # create dictionary mapping scores to names
        array1.sort(reverse=True)  # sort scores in descending order
        for x in array1:
            value = array3.get(x)  # get the name corresponding to the score
            print("\n", x, ">>", value)  # print the score and corresponding name
        file.close()  # close the file

    def add_score(self, score, name):
        file = open("manager.txt", 'a')  # open file in append mode
        file.write(str(score) + " >> " + name + "\n")  # write new score and name to the file
        file.close()  # close the file

    def overwrite_score(self):
        file = open("manager.txt", 'r+')  # open file for reading and writing
        array1, array2, array3 = [], [], {}  # initialize empty lists and dictionary
        lines = file.readlines()  # read all lines from the file
        for x in lines:
            fields = x.split(" >> ")
            array1.append(int(fields[0]))  # convert score to int and append to array1
            array2.append(fields[1].replace("\n", ""))  # remove newline and append name to array2
            array3[int(fields[0])] = array2[-1]  # create dictionary mapping scores to names

        availableplayers = set(array2)  # create a set of available player names
        print("Available players:", availableplayers)  # print the available player names
        z = input("Enter the name of the player you want to update >> ")
        if z not in availableplayers:  # check if entered player name is valid
            print(f"Player '{z}' not found. Please choose from the available players.")
            file.close()
            return
        r = int(input("Enter the new score >> "))
        for i, playername in enumerate(array2):
            if z == playername:
                array1[i] = r  # update the score for the specified player
        file.seek(0)  # move the file cursor to the beginning
        file.truncate()  # clear the file content
        for i in range(len(array1)):
            file.write(str(array1[i]) + " >> " + array2[i] + "\n")  # write updated scores and names to the file
        file.close()  # close the file
```

Some stuff to consider about your code:

- you were using `file. Close()` in your code, please use `file.close()` instead.
- Also, very important, before you were trying to create an instance of `MyScoreboard` using `MyScoreboard()`, which was defined as `pass`. This would basically do nothing. This is where the beauty of oop comes in, you need to define methods and properties for your class. Which I did in my approach.
- Your logic for overwriting a score was incorrect. Instead, you should check if `z` was equal to the name in the loop (`fields[1].replace("\n", "")`)
- `r` was unused

However, do not get discourged, keep on learning. For a "homework", check a way to test if the user is giving numerical input for score, and prompt the user to input again if the user used nonnumerical input. Furthermore, maybe also better to use `name, score` as the way to go, instead of `score, name`.

Hope this helps you further, have a nice weekend.